# Passing Application object to class in a compose preview function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I have the following preview function:

```
@Preview(
    name = "Light Mode",
)
@Composable
fun LM_HomePageSecondaryBarPreview() {
    val viewModel = HomePageViewModel(
        projectRepository = ProjectRepository(LocalContext.current.applicationContext as Application)
    )

    ProjectCounterTheme {
        Surface {
            HomePageSecondaryBar(
                viewModel = viewModel
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to provide `ProjectRepository` with an Application object. ChatGPT  and it told me to do the above and I get the following error when it tries to build the preview:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.ApplicationContext cannot be cast to class android.app.Application
```

My question here is what do I need to do in order to pass `Application` to my `ProjectRepository` to be able to get the preview to work properly.

Comment: first of all please don't use ChatGPT for compose problems because compose is a new technology and GPT knowledge stops at 2021, second thing is can you provide the code for your ProjectRepository because i don't see why would you need context in a Repository